# Playonlinux won't download: 14.04

Tags: playonlinux

Either using commands in Konsole (this answer is given: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?), nor from Muon Software Centre (no response when clicking 'Install').
Any ideas or tips, please?
Cheers, X-Man